# How can I change sizes parameter of GPUComputationRenderer?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have `gpuCompute = new GPUComputationRenderer( sizeX, sizeY, renderer );` that I use for texture, and I would like update sizeX and sizeY, but I can't find any setter in the lib. Somone know if it is possible?

*GPUComputationRenderer is from three/examples/jsm/misc/GPUComputationRenderer*

Comment: See https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_gpgpu_birds_gltf.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to resize the renderer's dimensions after its creation.